# using method form generic class form interface

Tags: c#

i using generic service and write method in this class .

```
public class EfGenericService<T> : IGenericService<T> where T : class
{
    protected IUnitOfWork Uow;
    protected IDbSet<T> Entites;

    public EfGenericService(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        Uow = uow;
        Entites = Uow.Set<T>();
    }

    public virtual ResultStatus Add(T entity)
    {
        ResultStatus rs = new ResultStatus();
        try
        {
            Entites.Add(entity);
            Uow.MarkAsAdded(entity);
            rs.IsSuccessed = true;
            rs.Type = MessageType.Success;
            //rs.Message = .Data_Saved_Successfully;
            return rs;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            rs.IsSuccessed = false;
            rs.Type = MessageType.Danger;
            rs.ErrorException = e;
            //rs.Message = Messages.Error_In_Saving_Data;
        }
        return rs;
    }

    public virtual ResultStatus Update(T entity)
    {
        ResultStatus rs = new ResultStatus();
        try
        {
            Entites.Attach(entity);
            Uow.MarkAsChanged(entity);
            rs.IsSuccessed = true;
            rs.Type = MessageType.Success;
            //rs.Message = Messages.Data_Edited_Successfully;
            return rs;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            rs.IsSuccessed = false;
            rs.Type = MessageType.Danger;
            rs.ErrorException = e;
            //rs.Message = Messages.Error_In_Editing_Data;
        }
        return rs;
    }

    public virtual ResultStatus UpdateAll(IQueryable<T> updateEntites, Expression<Func<T, T>> updatExpression)
    {
        ResultStatus rs = new ResultStatus();
        try
        {
            updateEntites.Update(updatExpression);
            rs.IsSuccessed = true;
            rs.Type = MessageType.Success;
            //rs.Message = Messages.Data_Edited_Successfully;
            return rs;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            rs.IsSuccessed = false;
            rs.Type = MessageType.Danger;
            rs.ErrorException = e;
            //rs.Message = Messages.Error_In_Editing_Data;
        }
        return rs;
    }

    public virtual ResultStatus Delete(T entity)
    {
        ResultStatus rs = new ResultStatus();
        try
        {
            Entites.Remove(entity);
            rs.IsSuccessed = true;
            rs.Type = MessageType.Success;
            //rs.Message = Messages.Data_Removed_Successfully;
            return rs;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            rs.IsSuccessed = false;
            rs.Type = MessageType.Danger;
            rs.ErrorException = e;
            //rs.Message = Messages.Error_In_Removing_Data;
        }
        return rs;
    }

    public virtual ResultStatus DeleteAll(IQueryable<T> deleteEntites)
    {
        ResultStatus rs = new ResultStatus();
        try
        {
            Uow.Set<T>().RemoveRange(deleteEntites.AsEnumerable());
            rs.IsSuccessed = true;
            rs.Type = MessageType.Success;
            //rs.Message = Messages.Data_Removed_Successfully;
            return rs;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            rs.IsSuccessed = false;
            rs.Type = MessageType.Danger;
            rs.ErrorException = e;
            //rs.Message = Messages.Error_In_Removing_Data;
        }
        return rs;
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<ResultStatus> ValidateCreate(T entity)
    {
        return new List<ResultStatus>().AsEnumerable();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<ResultStatus> ValidateUpdate(T entity)
    {
        return new List<ResultStatus>().AsEnumerable();
    }

    public T Find(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return Entites.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public IList<T> GetAll(bool asNoTracking = false)
    {
        return asNoTracking ? Entites.AsNoTracking().ToList() : Entites.ToList();
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAllAsQueryable(bool asNoTracking = false)
    {
        return asNoTracking ? Entites.AsNoTracking().AsQueryable() : Entites.AsQueryable();
    }

    public IList<T> GetAll(Func<T, bool> predicate, bool asNoTracking = false)
    {
        return asNoTracking ? Entites.AsNoTracking().Where(predicate).ToList() : Entites.Where(predicate).ToList();

    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAllAsQueryable(Func<T, bool> predicate, bool asNoTracking = false)
    {
        return asNoTracking ? Entites.AsNoTracking().Where(predicate).AsQueryable() : Entites.Where(predicate).AsQueryable();
    }

    public IQueryable<T> AllIncluding(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = Uow.Set<T>();
        return includeProperties.Aggregate(query, (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));
    }
    #region IDisposable Members
    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    #endregion

}
```

and this interface :

```
public interface IGenericService<T> : IDisposable where T : class
{
    ResultStatus Add(T entity);
    ResultStatus Update(T entity);
    ResultStatus UpdateAll(IQueryable<T> updateEntites, Expression<Func<T, T>> updateExpression);
    ResultStatus Delete(T entity);
    ResultStatus DeleteAll(IQueryable<T> deleteEntites);
    IEnumerable<ResultStatus> ValidateCreate(T entity);
    IEnumerable<ResultStatus> ValidateUpdate(T entity);
    T Find(Func<T, bool> predicate);
    IList<T> GetAll(bool asNoTracking = false);
    IQueryable<T> GetAllAsQueryable(bool asNoTracking = false);
    IList<T> GetAll(Func<T, bool> predicate, bool asNoTracking = false);
    IQueryable<T> GetAllAsQueryable(Func<T, bool> predicate, bool asNoTracking = false);
    IQueryable<T> AllIncluding(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties);
}
```

i use this generic class in `User` Entite .

```
public interface IUser : IGenericService<User>
{

}
```

class :

```
public class EFUserService : EfGenericService<User>, IUser
{
    public EFUserService(IUnitOfWork uow) : base(uow)
    {
    }
}
```

now . i need use `Find` method in `EfGenericService` for login code .

i using this in my class `private readonly IUser _userservice;`

but it can not find `Find` method . whats the problem ? how can i solve this ?

***update***

write this code for login in `EFUserService`:

```
public User FindUser(string username, string password)
        {
            return Find(x => x.Username == username && x.Password == password);
        }
    }
```

*** `EFUserService` in other class library and i need to use this method in main program .

now i write this code in main program :

```
  `private readonly IUser _userservice;`
```

it can not find `FindUser` .

Comment: What do you mean you can't "find" the method? It's there...

Comment: i need to write code for login . i need use the `Find` method in `GenericService` in`EfUserService` for find user

Comment: So `_userservice.Find(...)` right?

Comment: it can not find

Comment: First of all do you add `EfGenericService<User>` AND `IUser` on purpose? You will depent on `IGenericService<User>` twice. I don't know if this is a problem but I wanted to double-check if this is intended. And second: What means you can't find `Find`? Does the Compiler complain about it or is IntelliSense just not showing it?

Comment: What does that mean? You need to explain a lot more.

Comment: ok .how can i write code for login by this methods ??

Comment: Like this: `var user = x.Find(u => u.Id == 123);`?

Comment: by this method in `Genericservice` : 
`public T Find(Func<T, bool> predicate)
        {
            return Entites.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
        }`

Comment: The question is not clear and the comments neither. I don't know what you want to do. How is `_userservice` initialized? I don't see its declaration inside your class. Please post complete code and explain your problem in more detail. Otherwise nobody can help you.

Comment: @DavidG update question

Comment: @RobertS. update question

Comment: Why would you assume that `IUser` has a method called `FindUser`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the question was updated, here my new answer:

`FindUser` is not part of `IUser`. It is declared only in `EFUserService`.

So try this in your main program:

```
private readonly EFUserService _userservice;
```

If you want to keep it as `IUser` you can do this:

```
private readonly IUser _userservice = new EFUserService();

// ...

(_userservice as EFUserService).FindUser(...);
```

Comment: thans it find but can you help me to use `StructureMap` ?